# Passing multiple values for 'nelder mead' scipy optimizer

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I am trying to run a minimization using scipy with nelder mead unconstrained.

My objective function is:

```
def obj (self, x): 
    return self.fitn(x[:4], x[4],x[5],x[6]) 

def fitn(self, a, b,c,d):
   'some utility function using a,b,c,d'

 p = scipy.optimize.minimize(self.obj,np.array(a),args=(b,c,d),
                                        method='nelder-mead')
```

Wherein,

```
a =[0.25,0.25,0.25,0.25]
b = scalar value
c = 4 x 4 matrix
d = 1 x 4 matrix
```

I am facing this message:

```
obj() takes 2 positional arguments but 5 were given
```

Comment: The function is `self.obj`. It is handed down the `self` instance (1st arg), the optimization variable (2nd arg) and then the content of `args` (3rd to 5th args). Use `def obj(self, a, *args)` for instance and pass `*args` to `fitn` as `self.fitn(a, *args)`.

Answer (score 0):

As Pierre de Buyl said,

```
minimize(self.obj, np.array(a), args=(b,c,d), ...
```

results in 5 positional arguments passed to obj: self, a, b, c, d. The `minimize` method does not pack all the arguments into `x`.

Since the method `obj` was declared with two arguments, `def obj (self, x)`, there is an error. It would be consistent to write

```
def obj (self, x, b, c, d):
```

which I think also eliminates the need for the list unpacking that your `obj` is doing now; so the `obj` loses its purpose and can be replaced with `fitn`.